# "worth" with possessive(s) in coordinated nominals

Tags: adjectives, british-english, writing-style, formality, possessives

According to Garner Modern English Grammar

> The idiomatic possessive should be used with periods of time and
>   statements of worth — 30 days’ notice (i.e., notice of 30 days), three
>   days’ time, 20 dollars’ worth, and several years’ experience.

Yet, I'd like to know how to use  the possessive in coordinated nominals. 
I've just come across

*This is **two Christmases and a birthday** worth of presents*

Comment: [Related](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/600416/2085).